# shouldn't `init(repeating:count)` be working by reference?

Tags: arrays, swift, reference, initialization

I tried this code in a playground:

```
var a = [String](repeating: String(), count: 2)
a[0] = "string"
a[1]
```

The last line prints the content of `a[1]` which is `""`.

Shouldn't it be `"string"`, since I am passing a reference of an object to the constructor of the array `a`?

Does this mean that 2 objects of type `String` are created instead of just one repeated 2 times?

EDIT:

as pointed out by an user, the behaviour I was looking for is reproduced by the following code

```
import UIKit

class A {
    var str = "str"
}

var a = [A](repeating: A(), count: 2)
a[0].str = "a"
Swift.print(a[1].str) //this prints "a"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are not passing a reference. All strings are value types (not reference types). They are always copied.

Even if you passed a reference, it would be an initial value. Assigning a new reference to `a[0]` would not change the contents of the reference.

Too see the behavior for a reference, let's declare a real reference type:

```
class RefType {
    var value: String

    init(_ value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

var a = [RefType](repeating: RefType("x"), count: 2)
// the same reference in both indices
print(a[0].value) //x
print(a[1].value) //x

// let's change the value of the reference
a[0].value = "y"
// still the same reference in both indices
print(a[0].value) //y
print(a[1].value) //y

// let's change one of the references to a new object
a[0] = RefType("z")
print(a[0].value) //z
print(a[1].value) //y
```

Comment: Your new edit is very similar to mine, but more complete

Comment: Related to what I just asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894919/allocate-an-array-of-a-reference-type-of-a-certain-size